# Which is faster in Parallel data warehouse : Delete or Update?

Tags: database, t-sql, sql-update, sql-delete, parallel-data-warehouse

In Interview I have been asked that can you tell me which is faster in parallel data warehouse : Delete or Update?

So first I would ask :
1. In general which process is faster? 
2. What if we are doing operation on column with Index? 
3. Which one is faster in Parallel Data Warehouse?

Comment: The answer for the 'general' case is going to be 'it depends'. Question 2 there indicates why its not so straight forward.

Comment: Is it a columnstore? Deletes on columnstores just flag the row as deleted which isn't super expensive.